# How do I Reauthorize Screen Sharing for Quicktime?

Tags: video, quicktime, screen-sharing

At some point, I must have denied Quicktime access to screen sharing.  Now that I want to record a Screen Recording, I need to grant it permission again however, when I go to System Preferences to do this, Quicktime does not appear as one of the options to check.  Where did it go?  Is Quicktime holding a grudge because I denied it previously?  How do I Reauthorize Quicktime for Screen Sharing?

[image]

Comment: how come "*I need to grant it permission again*" ? where does it ask? Can you post a screenshot ?

Comment: Open Quick time and when you click New Screen Recording, it should pop up again asking you to grant permission. Did you try that?

Comment: Your title & intro refer to screen sharing, yet your issue seems to relate only to screen recording. Can you clarify.

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer below.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reset Screen Recording permission on macOS Catalina?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/384231/18101)

Answer (score 3):

You can [reset the screen recording permissions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/384230/18101) for QuickTime Player using `tccutil`:

```
tccutil reset ScreenCapture com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX
```

After running this command, you need to quit QuickTime Player (if it was open). Then open QuickTime Player again and choose "New Screen Recording..." from the File menu. That will cause the prompt dialog to pop up again so you can grant permission for Screen Recording.

Answer (score 1):

Quitting and restarting Quicktime several times seems to have made it a selectable option in System Preferences.  Once it was selected/checked I was able to perform a screen recording with Quicktime.

Answer (score 1):

Running a `tccutil reset` command did *not* help me. No apps appeared in the Screen Recording list, as shown in the screen shot of the original poster, and I couldn't figure out how to add them back.

Nic, who posted about a [similar situation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/384230/how-do-i-reset-screen-recording-permission-on-macos-catalina/384315), suggested that I create a new login user account and log in there, and *then* get QuickTime Player to record the screen in the new account. This worked for me. Here's what I did:

Starting in my main user account, I created a User 2 account with admin privileges and then switched accounts. In the new account, I launched QuickTime as well as a couple other relevant apps (screen shot and screen sharing apps). Each time I did that, I got the usual prompts to allow Screen Recording access and those apps finally appeared in the list so that I could check them.

When I finally switched back to my regular user account, those permissions were retained, so that I could finally run QuickTime and make screen recordings.

Hope this works for you too.

Comment: I had the exact same problem where QuickTime is not in the list of apps. Quitting QuickTime and restarting it several times does not make it appear, and tccutil reset also didn't make it appear. Creating a second admin account seems to be the solution here - and with fast user switching you don't even need to restart after doing so. Deleting it after is also quite trivial, just click the minus button in Users and Groups.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this, was open QuickTime, start a recording, tried to give permission and if I didn't see Quicktime there I closed QuickTime and repeated the process a lot of times until it appeared in System preferences.